# ImportError: Symbol not found [画像解析ソフト Gwyddion を pythonで使用したい]

Tags: python, anaconda

画像解析用フリーソフト Gwyddion (http://gwyddion.net/documentation/pygwy.php) に付属でついてくる python package "gwy" を import すると、以下のような error が返ってきます。
libgwyprocess2.0.dylib が参照しようとした gwy.so の中にあるはずの _sincos がない、という意味だと思っているのですが、あっているのでしょうか。
Gwyddion 自体は homebrew で install したのですが、他に同じような状況の方がいましたら助力ください。
その他、何か確認できるような手段、項目を知っている方がいれば助言くださると助かります。
どんなことでも結構です。当方初心者のため、打つ手なく行き詰まっております。

```
>>> import gwy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gwy.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sincos
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gwyddion/2.47_1/lib/libgwyprocess2.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/gwyddion/2.47_1/lib/libgwyprocess2.0.dylib
```

python の version は
Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)
になります。

2017.4.22 追記
Gwyddion の version を追記致します。

```
gwyddion --version
Gwyddion 2.47
```

2017.8.29 追記
Gwyddion の update (ver. 2.49) により問題が解決しました。

Comment: 関係あるか分かりませんが、Gwyddionのメーリングリストに最近 (2017年4月3日) ソースからコンパイルしたときに `sincos` まわり等でエラーが出るバグがあり、修正している、という旨のスレッドがありました。 https://sourceforge.net/p/gwyddion/mailman/gwyddion-users/thread/CA%2ByMqGkb83mjLfheKTSU1WNQgGBy_CJ_PnZ7%2BZE3YBLOyoEg2g%40mail.gmail.com/#msg35763310

Comment: クリーンなUbuntu 16.04上でpython2.7とGwyddion 2.44をaptからインストールしてみると、（ライブラリのファイル名を多少直さないといけなかったことを除いて）python2.7のREPLの上で`import gwy`がちゃんと動きました。Max OS固有の問題なのかもしれません。

Comment: 後からこの質問を見に来た人のために、Gwyddionのバージョンを追記してくださいませんでしょうか？

Comment: お調べくださったようで大変ありがとうございます。色々と勝手がわからずご迷惑おかけしました。バージョン追記させていただきました。

Comment: インストールしてくださったということでしたので、差し支えなければ確認させていただきたいのですが、gwy.so の中に _sincos はありますでしょうか。私の場合 nm gwy.so | grep _sincos などをしても返ってこないため、私の環境 (Gwyddion 2.47) では確かに存在していないのかなと考えているところです。

Comment: 私の環境で `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gwy.so` に対して `nm gwy.so | grep _sincos` とすると `nm: gwy.so: no symbols` と出力されました。`nm --dynamic gwy.so` はいくつかシンボル名を返してきましたが、その中に `_sincos` はありませんでした。ただし、`/usr/lib/` 下にあった `libgwyddion2.so`、`libgwydgets2.so` および `libgwyprocess2.so` には (`_sincos`ではなく) `sincos` があることが分かりました (`nm --dynamic`で調査しました)。

Comment: Gwyddionのメーリングリストで聞いてみるのも手かもしれません。 https://sourceforge.net/p/gwyddion/mailman/gwyddion-users/